# Incorrect question asked date and question answered date in UI

Tags: bug, dates

I asked the question several days ago and it was answered several days ago whereas the UI shows that I asked this question yesterday and it was answered yesterday, which is wrong. Question [Order rows by product category name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59021853/order-rows-by-product-category-name). I now see that the question was asked 2 days ago and it was answered 2 days ago while today morning it said asked yesterday. Also, if when hovered the mouse over the date it said "2019-11-24" so it clearly shows that there is a bug in the timezone.

Comment: Are you aware that the timestamps are in UTC? The tooltip says `2019-11-24 20:05:19Z`. `Z` means UTC.

Answer (score 6):

If I'm understanding you correctly: this isn't a bug, just a quirk of how the "asked on X day" display is calculated.

By "2 days ago", it actually means "48 hours ago". Because you asked your question at 2019-11-24 20:05:19Z, it would have changed from "asked yesterday" to "asked 2 days ago" at 2019-11-26 20:05:19Z, which was about two hours ago. This avoids having to display different lengths of time for different people depending on which time zone they're in.

The good news is, once 72 hours have elapsed, the display changes again to show the actual date and time at which you asked the question, and stays like that. In the case of your question, this will happen in about 22 hours' time, and the problem you're complaining about will cease to exist.